# Kafka-Connect For MSSQL Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for for configuration

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect kafka-connect to my local mssql with `localhost:3030`
I am receiving this error when I try to make a new connection for mssql. in centos 7(linux). Mssql data is from an external IP(windows), my consumer is inside of linux environment.

> "No suitable driver found for configuration".

`connect-distributed.properties` is shown below;

```
plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
```

I added `"ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar"` file under `/opt/connectors/kafka-connect-jdbc/` but still I am receiving error messages. I dont know what is wrong.

Also my connect-console-source.properties

```
name=source-sqlserver-user
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
topic.prefix=my-timestamp
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://externalIP;database=database;username=username;password=password
```

```
version: '2'

services:
  kafka-cluster:
    image: landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0
    environment:
      ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1          
      RUNTESTS: 0                 
    ports:
      - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
      - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
      - 8081-8083:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
      - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
      - 9092:9092                 # Kafka Broker
```

Comment: Why not use a newer version of that container?

Comment: how can I update it?

Comment: Look at the tags of that docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/fast-data-dev/tags

Comment: If the database is on a remote server, why are you using 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I thought that was kafkaconnect IP address.

Comment: I wrote this command ```docker run --rm --net=host --volume ~/Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:/opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0``` and still trying to run it. Is it normal? I opened the kafka-connect localhost page. But still trying to run

Comment: You can still use Docker-Compose, but `--net=host` only works on Linux, not Windows. You say MSSQL is running on a remote machine, so pointing the JDBC address to localhost won't accomplish that

Comment: so I am changing docker-compose ADV_HOST: IP address which has mssql right?

Comment: Nope. That is the advertised IP of the Kafka broker, not Connect or your database. You need to change `connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1`

Comment: Still driver error. I think I am making mistakes in both ```plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,``` location and ```docker run --rm --net=host --volume ~/Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:/opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0``` I am using mobaxterm to connect linux I add ```mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar``` file inside ```Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar/``` should must work or is there a mistake?

Comment: I don't think `plugin.path` worked until Confluent 4.0.

Comment: then th problem is in docker run --rm --net=host --volume ~/Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:/opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0

Comment: I add .jar file to /opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar but still same error how can I update 3.3.0 to 5.3.1 There is a small tiny thing missing but I cant find it

Comment: 1) Have you tried one of the newer Docker image tags that I linked to 2) I have only used the official Confluent Docker images, not the Landoop ones

Comment: I am trying now confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest image I add the inside of docker-compose image

Comment: but I get this error now When I start docker Command ```[/usr/local/bin/dub ensure CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS] FAILED !```

Comment: Because you're missing a lot of variables. That container requires running Zookeeper and Kafka separately... See the link in Robin's answer https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/connect-jdbc/docker-compose.yml#L55

Comment: Hi, I added ```mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar``` in root and when I run this command it goes in loop docker  ```run --rm --net=host --volume ~/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:/opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0```

Comment: ```INFO success: logs-to-kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
 INFO success: schema-registry entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
 INFO success: rest-proxy entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 1; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 570
 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)```

Answer (score 2):

`ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar` is the JDBC driver for Oracle.

For MS SQL you need the [MS SQL JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

---

*Edit:* Since you're using Docker to run Kafka Connect, you need to make the JDBC JAR file available to the Kafka Connect worker *before* it runs. You can't just run the Docker container and copy the JDBC driver into it, because you need to restart Kafka Connect afterwards.

To workaround this, you can mount the JAR from your local machine to the relevant path in the container. The relevant path is whereever the Kafka Connect JDBC jar is. Looking at the `fast-data-dev` image it's in

```
root@fast-data-dev / $ ls -l /opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
total 6544
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  133842 Jul 28  2017 kafka-connect-jdbc-3.3.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  658466 Jul 28  2017 postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc41.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5575351 Jul 28  2017 sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar
```

So you can run

```
docker run --rm --net=host --volume ~/Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:/opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0
```

or mount it in your Docker Compose with a `volumes` config:

```
version: '2'

services:
  kafka-cluster:
    image: landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0
    environment:
      ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      RUNTESTS: 0
    ports:
      - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
      - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
      - 8081-8083:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
      - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
      - 9092:9092                 # Kafka Broker
    volumes:
      - ~/Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:/opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar
```

---

It's worth noting that Confluent Platform 3.3.0 is really old - the latest is 5.3.1. If you want to see an up-to-date example of running Kafka, Kafka Connect, SQL Server etc with JDBC driver automatically set up see [this example here](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/connect-jdbc/).

Comment: Do I need to add a new folder /opt/connectors/kafka-connect-mssql-jdbc/

Comment: No, just put the MS SQL JDBC jar under `kafka-connect-jdbc` just as you did with the other one

Comment: still same error message. I added ```mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar``` under kafka-connect-jdbc. But do I need to add under this path                                                    
```/opt/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/``` or                     ```/opt/connectors/kafka-connect-jdbc/```

Comment: Based on your `plugin.path` it should be under `/opt/connectors/kafka-connect-jdbc/`. BTW What version of Confluent Platform are you running? 5.3.1 is the latest - 3.3.0 is pretty old.

Comment: 3.3.0 version I am using

Comment: I add my docker-compose.yml file there is no problem inside of it right?

Comment: If you're using Docker Compose how are you installing the JDBC driver?

Comment: I am using docker compose and I installed Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4 for SQL Server. I extract the mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar file.

Comment: Now that I understand you're using Docker, the answer changes. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you need more help head to http://cnfl.io/slack

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you need more help head to http://cnfl.io/slack

Comment: consumer will be inside of linux but I am gonna get mssql data from extenal windows computer. Kafka inside of linux

Comment: I am sorry But I didnt get what did you change?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to mount a JDBC JAR into your docker container.

Comment: ~/Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar this is my local downloads location right?